# Rails 4.x relationships migration from Ruby 1.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are migrating some applications from Ruby 1.x to Ruby 4.x, not by choice.

I am finding that some of the relationships are no longer working.  Can someone please tell me if they can see anything in here that looks invalid to them based on rails 4.2.9?

In particular, here is what happens when I try to access the F5Device.nodes:

```
irb(main):003:0* f = F5Device.first
  SQL (7.8ms)  USE [Networks]
  F5Device Load (2.8ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [dbo].[f5_devices].* FROM [dbo].[f5_devices]  ORDER BY [dbo].[f5_devices].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY'
=> #<F5Device id: 5422, name: "myDevice", environment: "UAT", feed_type_id: 1, scm_device_id: 121764, created_at: "2012-08-23 20:02:52", updated_at: "2017-01-19 10:08:08", gonefishing: 0>
irb(main):004:0>
irb(main):005:0* f.nodes
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/charset.rb:13: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:68: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:69: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:70: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:325:in `inject'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:304:in `safe_constantize'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:572:in `safe_get'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:603:in `safe_constantize'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:154:in `block in compute_type'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:153:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:153:in `compute_type'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:295:in `compute_class'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:291:in `klass'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:118:in `klass'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:41:in `reader'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:115:in `nodes'
        from (irb):5
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**app/models/f5_device.rb**

```
class F5Device < F5Base
      has_many :nodes, :class_name => "F5Node", :foreign_key => "device_id"
      has_many :members, :through => :nodes
      has_many :group_items , :foreign_key => :device_id
      has_many :groups, :through => :group_items
      has_many :dependencies, :class_name => "Dependency", :foreign_key => :device_id
      has_many :device_applications, :class_name => "F5DeviceApplication", :foreign_key => :device_id
      has_many :applications, :through => :device_applications
      has_many :websphere_servers, :class_name => "IisDependency", :foreign_key => :f5_device_id
```

**app/models/f5_node.rb**

```
require 'f5'
class F5Node < F5Base
      has_many :bigips, :class_name => "F5Bigip", :foreign_key => :group_id, :primary_key => :group_id
      belongs_to :device, :class_name => "F5Device", :foreign_key => :device_id
      has_many :members, :class_name => "F5Member", :foreign_key => "node_id", :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :pools, :through => :members
      attr_accessor :ws, :bigip, :session_status, :monitor_status, :enabled_status, :status_description, :availability_status, :state
      after_initialize :set_ws
```

Comment: "We are migrating some applications from Ruby 1.x to Ruby 4.x" - I don't believe you....

Comment: Unless he means from ruby 1.x to the ruby required for rails 4.x, i.e. ruby 2.x?

Comment: At any way, he should not jump in versions while migrating ;)

Comment: Since the error is in soap4r and you're using a ten-year-old version, you might want to try upgrading to [soap4r-ng](https://github.com/rubyjedi/soap4r).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really are migrating your application from Rails 1.x to Rails 4.2:

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but the [official upgrade guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0) says

> If your application is currently on any version of Rails older than 3.2.x, you should upgrade to Rails 3.2 before attempting one to Rails 4.0.

Likewise,

> If your application is currently on any version of Rails older than 3.1.x, you should upgrade to Rails 3.1 before attempting an update to Rails 3.2.

Etc.

It seems like the official upgrade path is:

1. 1 to 3.0 ... I couldn't find instructions [in the upgrade guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) or any hints in the [complete release notes blog since the very start of rails](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/). I'm guessing the official path would be at most one major release at a time, but if you're gutsy you could jump right to 3.0 and see what happens.
2. [3.0 to 3.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-0-to-rails-3-1)
3. [3.1 to 3.2](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-1-to-rails-3-2)
4. [3.2 to 4.0](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0)
5. [4.0 to 4.1](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-0-to-rails-4-1)
6. [4.1 to 4.2](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-1-to-rails-4-2)